# Is there a way I can place an exsited shape on top of a slide with python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

Recently I plan to use pptx to generate a draggable network graph, but when I generate the graph, the nodes are always placed in the lowest layer, because I first place the nodes, and then generate the connecting lines. But I want the node can be placed at the top level so that people can see the nodes. Is there a way to solve this problem?
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the help from https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/49.
I've settled down this question.
The nodes are in front of the connectors, so I moved all the nodes in SHAPES to the end of the shapes using codes below.

```
for i in range(len(nodes)):
    cursor_sp = shapes[len(shapes)-1]._element
    cursor_sp.addnext(shapes[0]._element)
```